# VSTO Outlook Retrieving TimeZoneStruct from Appointment

Tags: c#, outlook, timezone, vsto, outlook-addin

### Short Version

I am attempting to access the [TimeZoneStruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/c7331d40-3e9d-4218-bf72-422693bac2a8) using VSTO from an Outlook Appointment.
The following error is thrown when attempting to access it.

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040102): Object does not support property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82330102".`

Interestingly, I am able to get a similar property, [TimeZoneDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/c7331d40-3e9d-4218-bf72-422693bac2a8), using the same method with no exceptions:
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8234001F`

My code is below; the first call to GetProperty succeeds, but the second does not.

```
//OK returns TimeZone Description string
dynamic tz1 = pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8234001F"); 

//NOK throws a COMException
dynamic tzStruct = pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82330102");
```

### Long Version

I am developing a plugin that reads the Outlook calendar.

Currently the difficulty is with recurring appointments that were created with different timezones that have different Daylight Savings Time settings.

In order to find all appointments of a recurring meeting series, I need timezone information.

The first approach I used was to obtain the timezone information by extracting the timezone name. This works in most cases but is not ideal.

```
Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = appointment.PropertyAccessor;
dynamic tz1 = pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8234001F");
```

This returns a string similar to `(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlijn, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Wenen`.

This works correctly, but appointments that were sent from PC's with different languages, or in the case of "old" meetings with "obsolete" timezones that were deleted in a Windows Update, this does not work so well.

I will get meetings from computers from other languages, for instance this timezone is in French and my computer will not find it.
`(UTC+03:00) Moscou, Saint-Pétersbourg, Volgograd`

There are also updates; this timezone below no longer exists. Volograd was put in its own timezone at UTC+04:00 in 2016. See [link from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914387/how-to-configure-daylight-saving-time-for-microsoft-windows-operating).

- Old: `(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd`
- New: `(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg`

Obviously, matching the timezone name is never going to work.

I am focusing on getting the full information using the [TimeZoneStruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/c7d7d00f-984c-4af6-9634-8c602eb05b5f) instead; which should allow me to create a custom TimeZoneInfo Object; and then later I will be able to convert it into Local Time.

My problem is that when attempting to access this struct, I am getting the following error:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040102): Object does not support property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82330102".`

I have looked at OutlookSpy and can see that the property is indeed accessible.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6; Outlook 2016; Visual Studio 2015; Windows 8.1.

Any suggestions?

### UPDATE

I'm trying to access this property using VBscript on Outlook Spy and getting a similar error.
The properties that are not PT_BINARY seem to work, for some reason.
Any ideas?

#### here's how to repeat the experiment

Using OutlookSpy, select a recurring appointment. 
Make sure you are selecting the master and open the "Current Item" to run a script on the current AppointmentItem.

Enter the following code.
See screenshot for reference.

```
set msg = AppointmentItem
set pa = msg.PropertyAccessor

debug.print pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8234001F")
debug.print pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82310003")
debug.print pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82330102")
```

[image: Trying to obtain property with OutlookSpy]

Comment: Google **Err.exe** it weirdly comes as a Exchange utility. Put it in you System32 folder or any path that's in an Environment Variable (this way you dont need to CD to the directory). Next issue this command `err 0x80040102` - now that should get you closer to the root cause. It's likely to be simple but Date Time conversions are tricky, good luck!

Comment: Hi @JeremyThompson. Thanks for the tip. Looks like it returns "MAPI_E_NO_SUPPORT". I'll look that up some more.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - i've tried your tool but cannot seem to get more info; the error is very generic. I've tried with OutlookSpy to get the data via VBscript but I'm getting the same problem (see updated screenshot above). Any references you might know?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] this is complex. We'll need to reproduce the issue in a debugger to give correct and quality advice.

Comment: Hello @JeremyThompson - you are right. I've posted directions in the "UPDATE" section in the question on how to reproduce the problem with OutlookSpy. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook likes to play the Big Brother to prevent you from modifying, or sometimes even accessing, some properties that it considers special.

Using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) instead of OOM is the only workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the information- this is indeed the problem. Redemption library is very powerful. And this put me on the right track. I am currently trying to access the method using PInvoke. A developer named Helmut Obertanner has provided a very powerful code sample as well: http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1112